# ASP.Net How prompt user to upload an image and store it to a database?

Tags: asp.net, database, image, image-uploading

I have a user registration page and would like to by clicking on browse button allow the user to select an image from the local machine and would upload it to the database. The image can then be retrived for that user to display it next to their name on a ASP.Net webpage.

I have never done this before nor can I find anything on the web. Therefore, can someone direct me to a page or be kind enough to show me how to code the process of selecting and uploading the image into the Access database. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this site has an example on how to do it:
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/123/Storing-Files-and-Images-in-Access-with-ASP.NET